# get first row for each group

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I want to transform this data

```
account; docdate; docnum
17700; 9/11/2015; 1
17700; 9/12/2015; 2
70070; 9/1/2015; 4
70070; 9/2/2015; 6
70070; 9/3/2015; 9
```

into this

```
account; docdate; docnum
17700; 9/12/2015; 2
70070; 9/3/2015; 9
```

.. for each account I want to have one row with the most current (=max(docdate)) docdate. I already tried different approaches with `cross apply` and `row_number` but couldn't achieve the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELCT account, docdate, docnum
FROM (
  SELECT account, docdate, docnum,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account 
                            ORDER BY docdate DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`PARTITION BY account` clause creates slices of rows sharing the same `account` value. `ORDER BY docdate DESC` places the record having the maximum `docdate` value at the top of its related slice. Hence `rn = 1` points to the record with the maximum `docdate` value within each `account` partition.

Comment: thanks a lot, that works perfect. Just out of curiosity as I couldn't get it working with `cross apply`, what would be the respective `cross apply` syntax to get the desired result?

Comment: @user3716424 Something like this: `SELECT t1.account, t1.docdate, t1.docnum
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT MAX(docdate) AS maxDate
  FROM mytable AS t2
  WHERE t2.account = t1.account         
) AS t3(maxDate)
WHERE t1.docdate = t3.maxDate`